# Python function that counts negative integers using arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

Python newbie here, I need help with working with function with arbitrary number of parameters.

I want to implement a function that can take an arbitrary number of parameters, and counts negative integers. I want to try the `negative_counter` function on the following list of numbers `4,-3,5,6,-7`

See my attempt (not sure what I am doing wrong)

```
def negative_counter(*args):
    # setting the negative count to 0
    neg_count = 0
    # iterating through the parameters
    for x in args:
    # negative numbers are less than 0
        if args < 0:
    # adding 1 to negative number
            neg_count = neg_count + 1
            return neg_count

# driver code 
negative_counter([4,-3,5,6,-7]) 

#Desired output should return 2 since -3 and -7 are the negative integers
```

Please publish your code as you respond. Thanks

Comment: You have the `return` *inside the loop*, so it will always end the function when the count reaches 1.  Unindent that line by two levels.

Comment: @jasonharper, Please can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code:

- You've specified that the function take a single variadic argument, as discussed in [the Arbitrary Arguments List documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). So, `args` ends up being a list with one element, the list you're passing in your driver.
- You need to perform a comparison against `x` instead of `args`.

Here are examples that show demonstrate working with variadic arguments as well as [unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), along with a simplified implementation:

```
def negative_counter(*args):
    neg_count = 0
    for x in args:
        if x < 0:
            neg_count = neg_count + 1
    return neg_count

def negative_counter_list(num_list):
    neg_count = 0
    for x in num_list:
        if x < 0:
            neg_count = neg_count + 1
    return neg_count

def negative_counter_simplified(*args):
    return len([x for x in args if x < 0])

numbers = [4, -3, 5, 6, -7]

# use "*numbers" to unpack the list
print(negative_counter(*numbers))

# use the function that actually expects the list
print(negative_counter_list(numbers))

# use the simplified implementation, once again unpacking the list
print(negative_counter_simplified(*numbers)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test.py
2
2
2
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems with your code. First, it should be `if x < 0` instead of `if args < 0` because x is an element in args. Second, you have a return inside the loop, so it ends the function after increasing the `neg_count` by one.

This code may be better and shorter ;)

```
only_neg = [num for num in args if num < 0]
neg_count = len(only_neg)
```

or

```
neg_count = sum(1 for i in args if i < 0)
```

Comment: Please can you share your code?

Comment: yes, check the answer again. Mark as answer if you found it helpful ;)